# LogicException: Container extension "jms_serializer" is not registered

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

i am trying to add FosComment bundle , FOS Rest Bundle, JMS serializer

i get error LogicException: Container extension "jms_serializer" is not registered

when they are installed.
 \can anyone suggest to resolve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make sure you are using tag 0.9, as suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/181).